no me sale este trabajo
quiero realizar un árbol de procesos lineal en c que represente un flor. Se debe indicar el
número de procesos que integran los 5 TALLOS, las 3 FLORES y los 5PÉTALOS de
las flores  Al final el proceso raíz tiene que mostrar el total de
procesos que hay, el cual se obtiene apoyado de llamados sleep,wait y exit
esto es lo que llevo pero no sale algun consejo?
// Bucle para crear el árbol lineal
for (i = 1; i < t; i++) {
    pid = fork();  // Crear un nuevo proceso
    if (i == t - 1)  {// Si i es igual a t-1 (en este caso, 4)
        // Si estamos en el proceso hijo
        // Si i es 4, ejecutar el ciclo extra con f
        
            for (f = 0; f < 5; f++) {
                
                sleep(20);  // Añadir una pequeña pausa para observar el ciclo
            }
                if(j!=0){
                    if(!fork){

                    

        
                 // El proceso padre espera a que terminen todos los hijos
                      for (k = 0; k < -1; k++) {
                        if (k != p) {
                         
                        }
                    }
                    } else {
                    wait(NULL);  // Esperar a cada proceso hijo
                    exit(0);  // El proceso padre finaliza después de crear el hijo
                  }
                }
    }
}

sleep(30);  // Pausa para permitir observar el último proceso
return 0;

}

No entiendo bien el ejercicio pero estos links te deberían ayudar. https://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html https://youtu.be/Dt9z_ohQWHI

¿Podrías detallar más? Describe los detalles de la cuestión y hasta qué parte has entendido.
